# What is this plant growing in my backyard? I believe it's some kind of vegetable

Tags: identification

Does anyone recognize this plant?
I'm on Los Angeles, CA[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like white stemmed Swiss Chard, and it's about to flower.

http://www.rhsplants.co.uk/plants/_/leaf-beet-swiss-chard/classid.2000014686/

Comment: Similar, but the inflorescence is wrong. Not only the stem structure, but the actual flowers. I've had chard bolt on me before.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like lettuce in flowering stage

Comment: Looks more like to a brassica to me.